# .htaccess work with and without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess

Using .htaccess, how can I get my website to be able to do this. Here is what I have already.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ sites/index.php?url=$1&page=$2
```

From this, I am able to be able to browse to: 
http://domain.com/sites/example/ 
and that works totally fine. 
What I want to be able to do is browse to 
http://domain.com/sites/example 
with no trailing slash, but it always gives back an error with page not found.

So far from Google, all of the results have failed me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your regex to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*?)/?$ sites/index.php?url=$1&page=$2
```

The first `(.*)` is greedy, and will gobble up everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the sea of info in google can sometimes be a hinderance:
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ sites/index.php?url=$1&page=$2

Note the /? in the rewriterule before the $, sorry I've read your question backwards...

edited answer:
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?(.*)$ sites/index.php?url=$1&page=$2

The different position of the ? might help as otherwise the greedy match of the first(.*) might glob to the end and try and shove that all into $1, for the specifics you'd be best turning on the apache rewrite log and looking at that if you can.

Comment: This answer does not work for me. With the trailing slash, it goes to domain.com/sites/example/. But when I remove the trailing slash, it goes directly to domain.com/example and keep the sites part out.